# Number Format in java

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting

Is there a way to do a format on double to String in java where i would want the output as:

Intended output:

if n=12.4 => 12.4
if n=12.0 -> 12

I was using String.valueof(n) with returns 
Current output:
if n=12.4 => 12.4
if n=12.0 => 12.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat`:

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.#").format(12.0));
```

Comment: Use as many padding characters `#` as needed to cover the maximum number of decimal places.

Comment: right figured it out.. thats why i removed the comment immediately.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote this, and it worked well

```
    public static String formattedDouble(double d)
    {
        Long l = (d == Math.floor(d)) ? (long)d : null;
        String str = "";
        if (l == null)
            str += d;
        else
            str += l;
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to format double to string with two decimal  places use code like this

```
String.format("%1$,.2f", doubleValue)
```

for int use this

```
String.format("%d", intValue );
```